# How to include in code an unique ID related to a mercurial commit?

Tags: python, django, caching, mercurial

I'd like to do the same thing that they're doing here in stackoverflow.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sstatic.net/so/all.css?v=6274"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sstatic.net/so/js/master.js?v=6180"></script> 
<script src="http://sstatic.net/so/js/question.js?v=6274" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Do you see those `?v=...` ?
I'd like, at each commit, to change some variable in my code in order to make browsers refresh their cache when needed.

It may be even just one for each commit (it doesn't need to monitor each file in an independent way) but I'd like it to be automatically generated when I commit.

The difference is that I'm using mercurial and not subversion. Any hint?

Answer (score 4):

[KeywordExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordExtension) will let you put a keyword in a file whose results you can tear apart in order to get the hash.